# Cannot execute API call to another Laravel website

Tags: php, laravel, http, guzzle

Today I was trying to execute API call with Guzzle to another service.
But the problem is that if I do the request locally to that service, it works fine.
it should be mentioned that when the service was at Modx such error still reproduced. Currently service is replaced by Laravel app.

But when I do the request from the dev server if fails with following error:

```
`GET http://example.com/api/v1/products?codes=1` resulted in a `415 Unsupported Media Type` response:


production.ERROR: #0 /home/..../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(65): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#1 /home/..../vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(204): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#2 /home/.../vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(153): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), NULL)
```

`file_get_contents()` returns the same error. And when I open the link in browser it works fine

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The error message clearly states that you cannot `GET` http://example.com/api/v1/products?codes=1 - you probably have the URL, but not as a `GET`.

Comment: No. It works properly if I do request directly from browser without any problem. Additionally if I do request from local env with the same code it works fine for that example.com

Comment: Well, then you're doing something different between your browser and your `file_get_contents()`call, because that's what the error message says.

Comment: I have the following response headers:
{"responseHeaders":{"Date":["Mon, 04 Jan 2021 10:43:42 GMT"],"Content-Type":["application/octet-stream"],"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"Connection":["close"],"Server":["imunify360-webshield/1.13"]},"responseProtocol":"1.1"}

Comment: @Vladislav Could you please share request with `Guzzle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not pretty simple. Imunify360 protection has installed on the other side and blocked calls from my server.